# How to set HTTP request headers for WebView requests?

Tags: cordova

I'm building a hybrid app with Cordova 4 that communicates with a custom backend over HTTP. The backend authenticates each HTTP request using HTTP Basic authentication.

Including HTTP Basic authentication headers is simple for AJAX requests, but how do I set headers for requests resulting from app generated DHTML that are executed automatically by the platform WebView component? WebView doesn't appear to handle Basic authenication automatically if the server requires it.

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't.